# Encoding issue with Response filter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, encoding, utf-8

I am dealing with some code that uses a custom HttpResponse filter in an asp.net application.

```
response.Filter = new HtmlResponseFilterStream();
```

This *HtmlResponseFilterStream* inherits from *MemoryStream*. The write method has been overriden to get the contents of the HTTP response. I use  *Encoding.UTF8.GetString* to get the contents of the page in chunks.

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
        var contentInBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        ...
 }
```

In my local machine if I go to any page and debug the code I can see the the variable *contentInBuffer* populated with the actual html contents. Both with local ISS or iss express.
This also works in our production environment.

However, if I go to a test machine things don't work as expected. If I debug the contents inside the write method (using remote debugger). I get some weird characters instead. So I guess this is due to some different encoding used.. maybe..

Both production and test servers have same specs with same OS and iis server versions.

I checked .Net Globalization settings and the encodings are set to *UTF-8* for Request, Response Headers and Response in both machines.

I am pretty sure this has to be something related to the environment settings. Not sure if it's related with IIS or windows.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Weird characters must be due to GZip compression, it is called "Dynamic Compression" which is usually not installed by default but looks like your test machine has it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I already checked the dynamic compression and it is enabled in all servers. So it shouldn't be that